# C++ Embed image pixels inside vector at compile time?

Tags: c++, vector

I usually use [Sean Barrett's](http://nothings.org/) minimalist image loading library to read/write an image to an array of pixels and usually that is an std::vector of unsigned char and each pixel is represented by 4 unsigned char values (R 0-255 G 0-255 B 0-255 A 1-255).

What I would like to know is if I can some how embed an image (or more) in to my C++ program at compile time so that at runtime the std::vector is already populated with pixels and ready to use. That's because my application has a bunch of images that are used as default textures if not specified otherwise.

My compiler is MinGW GCC 4.8.2

EDIT:
Based on the answers posted so far and what other answers I found while browsing I came up with this temporary solution.

A small program to convert my images to code as an array of bytes.

convert_file_to_code.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("f2bytes row file\n");
        printf("row = after how many bytes to add a new line (0 for continuous)\n");
        printf("file = the name of the input file that should be converted\n");
        printf("note: a new file with the same name but .cpp appended will be create as output");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int rowl = atoi(argv[1]);

    std::string fsn(argv[2]);
    std::string fdn(argv[2]);
    fdn.append(".cpp");

    FILE* fs = fopen(fsn.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!fs)
        printf("Failed to open source file %s \n", fsn.c_str());

    FILE* fd = fopen(fdn.c_str(), "w");
    if (!fd)
        printf("Failed to open destination file %s \n", fdn.c_str());

    printf("transferring from %s to %s with row length of %d", fsn.c_str(), fdn.c_str(), rowl);

    fprintf(fd, "static const unsigned char file_data[] = {");

    if (rowl != 0) fprintf(fd, "\n");

    int n = 0;
    while(!feof(fs)) {
        unsigned char c;
        if(fread(&c, 1, 1, fs) == 0) break;
        fprintf(fd, "0x%.2X,", (int)c);
        ++n;
        if(rowl !=0 && n % rowl == 0) fprintf(fd, "\n");
    }

    fprintf(fd, "};\n");

    fclose(fs);
    fclose(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A program that uses the file data to convert the array of bytes to an array of pixels at runtime.

sample_program.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "stb_image.h"

#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "stb_image_write.h"

static const unsigned char file_data[] = {0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47,0x0D,0x0A,0x1A /* ... more data */};

int width, height, channel;
std::vector<unsigned char> pixel_data;

void read_data()
{
    // I know the image is a png data
    unsigned char* ptr = stbi_load_from_memory(&file_data[0], sizeof(file_data), &width, &height, &channel, STBI_rgb_alpha);

    if (ptr && width && height)
    {
        // Copy the loaded pixels to the pixel buffer
        pixel_data.resize(width * height * 4 /* R+G+B+A */ );
        memcpy(&pixel_data[0], ptr, pixel_data.size());

        // Free the loaded pixels
        stbi_image_free(ptr);

        printf("Loaded: %d x %d image \n", width, height);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed: %s\n", stbi_failure_reason());
    }
}

void write_data(const std::string& file)
{
    std::string filename(file);
    filename.append(".png");
    if (!stbi_write_png(filename.c_str(), width, height, 4, &pixel_data[0], 0))
        printf("Could not save %d x %d image to file %s\n", width, height, filename.c_str());

}

int main(void)
{
    read_data();
    write_data("myimage");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That's what I've got so far. And BTW the images don't need to be replaced at compile time so this solution works so far.

I'm guessing that I'm wasting some memory by keeping file_data[] after I read the pixels but I'll find a way to trash it after I read the pixels.

Comment: -1 from me because it is yet another OP changing the meaning (although just in answer comments!) after the original (and valid) question is answered.

Comment: I simply wanted the image data to be embedded into my executable code at compile time instead of loading it at runtime from an external file. And (only) if possible to be already stored inside an std::vector instead of reading from an array of bytes. But the last part is only if possible.

Comment: So what is wrong about my answer? I think I intended to cover that case. What are you missing from it (apart from the exact code)? Admittedly, I was not writing the code for you. :-)

Comment: I might get penalized because this is off topic but there's nothing wrong with your answer. I just gave it time to see if there are any other answers. It's not similar to an auction and I have to approve the first answer that comes in. But I'm guessing that enough time has passed so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: OK, but I did not mean to ask you to accept my answer. I was just wondering that you saw it, and I did not get critics that I would understand. It is possible that my understand is not OK, but I would need to understand it in order to help further or learn from the situation. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would write some C++ "code" generator code that reads the images into your data storage, and extends your existing source code with that.

This program would be pre-compiled and run as part of the build process. You could do this in C++ as well, for sure, but such things are usually better written in scripting languages, like python, because performance is not a main concern usually.

Comment: Thanks for the info but the images don't need to be replaced at compile time :)

Comment: `What I would like to know is if I can some how embed an image (or more) in to my C++ program at compile time so that at runtime the std::vector is already populated with pixels and ready to use.`

Comment: Bad expression :) I didn't wanted the image to be an external file and my program to depend on an image that could be missing sometimes if removed or corrupted.